# Nagios - NRPE: Command '...' not defined

Tags: apache, nagios, nrpe

In `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg` I added a new command `check_this_process` to the already pre-defined ones:

```
command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 5 -c 10
command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
command[check_hda1]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/$
command[check_zombie_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 5 -c 10 -s$
command[check_total_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 150 -c 200
command[check_this_process]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 15 -c 20 -C name
```

This works:

```
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               my_host
        service_description     CPU Load
        check_command           check_nrpe!check_load
}
```

This doesn't:

```
define service{
        use                             local-service
        host_name                       my_host
        service_description             cron
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_this_process
}
```

and returns: `NRPE: Command 'check_this_process' not defined`

Comment: Did you try restarting the nrpe service on the remote server?  Did you restart the nagios service on your Nagios server?

Comment: Yep, I did. I noticed that there is a nrpe.cfg in `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg`  but also a nrpe.cfg in `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`. Both on the Nagios server, which were also the one I edited so far. I removed the nrpe plugin from my Nagios server with apt-get remove and now edited the nrpe.cfg on the monitored server. Still the same issue anymore and not too sure anymore where the to be edited nrpe.cfg is supposed to be.

Comment: Can you post the configuration from your Nagios server where the command `check_nrpe` is defined?  Also can you post any `nrpe.cfg` files (along with their paths) on your monitored server that you can find?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D7UNbV7d this is the one from my monitored server on `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`. On my nagios on `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg`: http://pastebin.com/8FCrQ9xi . On `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`: http://pastebin.com/SwkaeTPW

Comment: On your Nagios server, in your `nagios.cfg` file, do you also have something defined like `cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg`?  I ask this because in your service definition on your Nagios server, you define a service with a `check_command` value of `check_nrpe!check_this_process`, but I don't see where you've actually defined `check_nrpe` anywhere on your Nagios server.  I'll take a look at the `nrpe.cfg` configuration for your monitored server and write back, but can you track down your `check_nrpe` command definition on your Nagios server?

Comment: Just to confirm, on your monitored server, did you add `command[check_this_process]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 15 -c 20 -C name` to your `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` and restart the nrpe service?
Did you also define the `cron` service on your Nagios server and restart the nagios service?  Can your try executing `nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg` on your Nagios server and see if it outputs any errors or warnings?

Comment: Thanks, I just went through my `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg` but couldn't find anything mentioning nrpe at all. I initially followed this tutorial to set it all up: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-4-and-monitor-your-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04 . On here it is also done like this: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf (page 13/14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology used in the supplied docs is a little confusing, but I'll put it like this:

As written in Page 10 of https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf, you need to modify `/usr/local/nagios/etc/commands.cfg` **on your Nagios server** and add the following to define the `check_nrpe` command:

```
define command{
    command_name check_nrpe
    command_line $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
```

On your Nagios server, define your service definition as you've already done:

```
define service{
        use                             local-service
        host_name                       my_host
        service_description             cron
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_this_process
}
```

**On your remote host to be monitored**, the following is going to be different depending on whether you installed NRPE:

- using the tarball and xinetd as in
  https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf
- or using a package manager like yum as in
  http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/03/02/how-to-install-and-configure-nagios-nrpe-in-centos-and-red-hat/

**If you used the tarball / xinetd method**, your NRPE configuration file will likely be located at `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg` on your remote-host-to-be-monitored.  *(To avoid typing that all the time, **I'll just call it "my_host"**).*
So, on **my_host**, modify `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg`.

Add

```
command[check_this_process]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 15 -c 20 -C name
```

So that it looks like:

```
command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 5 -c 10
command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
command[check_hda1]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/$
command[check_zombie_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 5 -c 10 -s$
command[check_total_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 150 -c 200
command[check_this_process]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 15 -c 20 -C name
```

*(**Note**: the above is assuming you have a process called `name`.  If not, replace `name` with your real process name: i.e. `crond`)*

Restart xinetd:

```
service xinetd restart
```

*(**NOTE:** restarting xinted might not be necessary, but I don't use it so I'm a little fuzzy on this one.)*

However, **if you installed NRPE on my_host using a package manager like yum**, your NRPE configuration file will likely be located at `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`.
So, on **my_host**, modify `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`.

Add

```
command[check_this_process]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 15 -c 20 -C name
```

So that it looks like:

```
command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 5 -c 10
command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
command[check_hda1]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/$
command[check_zombie_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 5 -c 10 -s$
command[check_total_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 150 -c 200
command[check_this_process]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 15 -c 20 -C name
```

Restart the nrpe service:

**service nrpe restart**

Back on your Nagios server, run a verification of your Nagios configuration settings:

```
nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

Check the output for errors.
If there are no errors, restart Nagios:

```
service nagios restart
```

On your Nagios server you should have a `check_nrpe` utility installed somehwere as a result of installing the "*check_nrpe plugin*" on your Nagios server.
*See pages 9 and 10 of:* https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf

This `check_nrpe` utility will most likely be located at:  `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe`
Using the host information for `my_host` manually test your NRPE connection **from the Nagios server**.
Execute the following:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H <IP Address of my_host> -c check_this_process
```

If everything is setup correctly, you should get some output on the command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed solution :) While I ended up completely redoing the installation, switched to Nagios3 from Nagios4 and had to change some paths, this really helped setting it up again and is now working fine so far :)

Answer (score 1):

My trouble-shooting guide for 'NRPE: Command ... not found.'  Ordered from most common to least common - in my environment.

1. Was the NRPE daemon restarted AFTER adding the new command?  If it is a new command, then NRPE MUST be restarted.
2. Typos/spelling errors.  Does the configured command name on the Nagios side, match that the one in the NRPE config?
3. Permissions issues.  Does the USER that NRPE runs as, have READABLE and EXECUTABLE access to the actual command being ran?  Did you test run the command, as the NRPE user?  On that same system?  TIP: Use the dash (-) when changing to the NRPE user on Linux (su - ...) so you import said users environment as well.
4. Path issues.  Was the FULL PATH to the actual command put into the NRPE config file?  Doing this will normally eliminate issues with PATHs, so don't do it any other way.
5. Bad commands.  Does the actual command really execute?  Or is it simply throwing an error and exiting?  Do you have the correct version of (INSERT SOMETHING HERE) to run the command, installed on the remote system?  You should be able to run any command defined in the nrpe.cfg from the command line, and all new commands should be checked BEFORE being added to the nrpe.cfg.
6. IF ALL THE ABOVE FAILS:  Enable DEBUGGING in NRPE and check the log files (on the remote host).  This is a bit of a drawn out process - described in the documentation - read it.  It is important to disable DEBUGGING as soon as you get output that looks like it would be useful.

This checklist ASSUMES that you've done the needful things to the various Nagios and NRPE configs to get it working in the first place.  Hopefully others will read this before posting yet another question as to why they are seeing this error.

Comment: Your first point did the trick for me. everything was in place except I didn't restart nrpe, after restarting nrpe issue got resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a good one that through me for a loop for 2 days.  It turned out that I had the IP address configured in the the host.cfg file for another machine.  It wasn't until I noticed that the stats being reported were *identical* that I finally clued.  Hope this helps someone else.